# Exchanging limit and expectation for $L^2$ random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables in $L^2$, i.e. $\mathbb E[\vert X_n \vert^2]<\infty$. Since the expectation value can be interpreted as a scalar product on $L^2$, can one exchange limit and expectation, without referring to theorems such as monotone convergence or dominated convergence, just using the continuity of the scalar product? :

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb E[X_n] \stackrel{?}{=} \mathbb E[\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n]$$

Comment: The hypothesis that each $X_n$ is square integrable does not guarantee the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity of scalar product implies $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}((X_n -X) \cdot Y_n)=0$$ for all $(Y_n)_n \subseteq L^2$ such that $\sup_n \|Y_n\|_2 < \infty$ and $X_n \stackrel{L^2}{\to} X$. As @Did already wrote, the equality $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}X_n = \mathbb{E} (\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n)$$ does not hold in general.

Consider for example the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}) := ([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\lambda|_{[0,1]})$ and define $X_n$ by $$X_n(x) := n \cdot 1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x) \qquad (x \in [0,1])$$ Then you can easily show $\|X_n\|_2<\infty$, but $$1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \underbrace{\mathbb{E}X_n}_{1} \not= \mathbb{E}(\underbrace{\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n}_{0})=0$$

Comment: Thanks! Consider for example an $L^2$ integrable process $X(t)$ and one wants to calculate $\mathbb E[\int_a^b X(t)dt] = \mathbb E[\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} X_{t_i} (t_{i+1} - t_i)]$. Now, I often read without a comment that limit and expectation are exchanged, but I don't see how this is justified by the condition you have written.

Comment: @madison54 Probably $(X_t)_t$ is a process such that $\mathbb{E}(\int_a^b |X(t)| \, dt)< \infty$ (this holds in particular if $\int_a^b \mathbb{E}(X_t^2) \, dt < \infty$). In this case, you obtain $\mathbb{E}(\int_a^b X(t) \, dt) = \int_a^b \mathbb{E}(X_t) \, dt$ by Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Thanks! Could I also take $Y_n \equiv 1$ in your statement? Then $sup_n \mathbb E[Y_n^2] = 1 < \infty$ and $Z_n:= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} X_{t_i} (t_{i+1}-t_i)\stackrel{L^2}{\rightarrow} Z:=\int_a^b X(t)dt$ and then the limit I was looking for in my comment would properly follow $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E[Z_n]=\mathbb E[Z]$

Comment: @madison54 Yes, if $Z_n \stackrel{L^2}{\to} Z$, this is correct. But in this case, it's simply the fact that $L^2$-convergence implies $L^1$-convergence (since $\mathbb{P}$ is a finite measure).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to show the exchangeability. Let $X$ be the $L^2$ limit of $\{X_n\}$. Then we have
$$\left| E[X_n]-E[X]\right| \leq E\left| X_n - X \right| \leq (E\left| X_n - X \right|^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}},$$
which implies that $E[X_n] \to E[X]$ as $n \to \infty$. The second inequality above is a special case of a corollary (see Corollary 3 in Real Analysis by Royden 4th Ed.(p142)):

"Let $E$ be a set of finite measure and $1\leq p_1 < p_2\leq \infty $. Then $||f||_{p_1}\leq c ||f||_{p_2}$ for any $f \in L^{p_2} (E)$, where $c=[m(E)]^{\frac{p_2-p_2}{p_2 p_1}}$ if $p_2<\infty$ and $c=[m(E)]^{\frac{1}{p_1}}$ if $p_2=\infty$."

Applying the collary to the current case where $m(E)=1$, $p_1=1$ and $p_2=2$, we can get the second inequality.