# How to show that $\mathbb{E}(\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n) = 0$ when $X_n(x) := n \cdot 1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x) \qquad (x \in [0,1])$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

from the answer of [Exchanging limit and expectation for $L^2$ random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361027/exchanging-limit-and-expectation-for-l2-random-variables):

> Consider for example the probability space
>   $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}) := ([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\lambda|_{[0,1]})$ and define $X_n$ by
>   $$X_n(x) := n \cdot 1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x) \qquad (x \in [0,1])$$ Then
>   you can easily show $\|X_n\|_2<\infty$, but $$1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \underbrace{\mathbb{E}X_n}_{1} \not= \mathbb{E}(\underbrace{\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n}_{0})=0$$

But for some reason I can't see why $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = 0$. I may be misunderstanding notations, things like $\lambda|_{[0,1]}$, or what $X_n$ exactly is referring to. Can anyone show how $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = 0$ gets resulted in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ is the pointwise limit of $X_n$.

Actually the pointwise limit of $X_n$ is $0$ almost surely, it is $0$ everywhere except at $0$. Why? Except at $x=0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(x) = 0$, since there always exists $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < x$.

The expectation of a function that is $0$ almost surely is $0$.

Comment: Why $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(x) = 0$ a.s.?

Comment: @d.k.o.  $X_n(x) := n$ if $x \in [0,\frac{1}{n}]$, and $0$ for $x \in (\frac{1}{n}, 1]$. This follows from the definition of $X_n$ and the indicator function. So for every $x$ in $(0, 1]$, there is some $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}<x$, so $X_n(x) = 0$ for all $n>N$. $\{0\}$, which is the only point where $X_n$ does not converge to $0$, is a null set in the Lebesgue measure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely#Formal_definition

Comment: @AMS just for fun $$X_n(x) := (\text{does not matter what I have here}) \cdot 1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x) \qquad (x \in [0,1])$$ then $X_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s.

Comment: I can not apply Borel Cantelli (divergent half) as $X_n$'s are not INDEPENDENT.

Comment: @Saty: yeah. classical example...