# Complete convergence not happening but convergence in probability occurs

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

So today I created a counterexample to "Convergence in Probability implies Almost Sure Convergence". I considered a sequence $\{X_n\}$ of independent random variables defined by: $P(X_n=n)=\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-\dfrac{1}{n}$.

As is evident, this sequence $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$ but does not converge "completely", so by using Second Borel-Cantelli Lemma and converse of Complete Convergence, $X_n$ does not converge almost surely.

I feel my example is correct and things are well-defined. However, when I told my professor of this counterexample, he said that I need to specify the probability space i.e. $\{\Omega,A,P\}$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space, $A$ is the usual collection of events and $P$ is the probability function.

He further added that I must show him, by constructing such a probability space, that $X_i$ independent of $X_j$ whenever $i\neq j$ happens, i.e. I am not saying anything fancy or unachievable.

Now, I have never worked with probability spaces before. I don't know how to construct one. Please tell me what more I need to tell my professor to convince him that my example is a valid counterexample. I will be able to understand what you mean if you completely specify the probability space. Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand your professor's concern. It looks to me like your example is complete and correct. In my opinion, adding more would only obfuscate an otherwise simple idea.

Comment: Perhaps he just wanted you to specify that the probability space $\Omega$ includes all countably infinite $0/1$ sequences. Sigma algebras for such things are "standard."

Comment: You can simplify your example to $Pr[X_n=1] = 1/n$, rather than $Pr[X_n=n]=1/n$, so that the space is $0/1$ sequences (I just noticed that, as you defined it, it is not 0/1 sequences).

Comment: Yes, specifying probability space will put a restriction on the problem. So 'independence' is enough to generalize the result. However if 'dependent' (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347759/how-to-show-that-mathbbe-lim-n-to-infty-x-n-0-when-x-nx-n-cd/1347763#comment2740211_1347763) then the above does not hold always and crucial to state the underlying probability space.

Comment: What is "complete" convergence? Not knowing that, I can't tell whether your argument is _correct_ or not; if it's actually wrong we don't need to worry about how to fix it up. As a check on the correctness: Say you changed things to $P(X_n=x^2)=1/n^2$, $P(X_n=0)=1-1/n^2$. Would you argument still work? Or did you use some property of $1/n$ that doesn't hold for $1/n^2$?

Comment: @Saty , it seems he already stated the $X_i$ variables were independent.  Perhaps he could have said "mutually independent."

Comment: I also do not  know what "converse of complete convergence" is, alghough you can just get rid of that since teh second Borel-Cantelli lemma is enough to prove $X_n =n$ infinitely often with prob 1.

Comment: $X_n$ converges completely to $X$ iff for any positive $\epsilon$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)<\infty$. The Borel Cantelli Lemmas give that if $X_n$ converges completely to $X$ then $X_n$ converges a.s. to $X$, and that the converse is also true if $X_n$ are independent.

Comment: I think then that Michael's suggestion to consider $P(X_n=1)=1/n$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-(1/n)$ is better then. Although I don't know why $0/1$ sequences are preferred and why I am supposed to describe a probability space when I believe that I have already said enough in the question. But again, that's what my professor wants.

Comment: I don't see any reason to prefer $0/1$ sequences either, but it is easier to write than "0/n sequences where the $n$th component can be either $0$ or $n$." I suspect the professor wants you to use notation he specifically used in class, perhasp the "sigma algebra generated by [blah blah blah]" and "product measure [blah blah]."

Comment: I think your teacher was being a bit pedantic.  There's nothing wrong with this counterexample.

Comment: I said I have not been taught about these sigma algebra and other measure theoretic concepts. I have never worked with such spaces before. It's the first time I am studying convergence concepts. However, my professor has no issue with the "popular" counterexample, which deals with something like $2^n$ if $X$ lies between $a$ and $b$, etc..

Comment: It sounds to me that if you want numeric values of $X_n$ to be large (but rarely so), then your professor thinks you are trying to do an example where the _limiting expectation_ is different from 0, while _you think_ you are doing an example where you just do not get convergence to 0.  So, I suspect tehre is mis-communication between you and your professor.  For example, your last comment sounds like you are describing an example where $X_n\rightarrow 0$ with prob 1, but $E[X_n] \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Landon, here is an example that matches what you are looking for and will also satisfy what your professor is asking for.

Consider $\{[0,1],A,\lambda\}$ where the closed interval $[0,1]$ is your sample space, $A$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the set of events, and $\lambda$ is the usual length measure (Lebesgue measure).

Let $\{[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}, B,P\}$ be countable infinite product space where each factor is $\{[0,1],A,\lambda\}$.

For the construction and existence of such product space, see *Halmos* $\S$38.

Each $\textbf{x}\in [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence $(x_0, x_1, x_2, ...)$, where, for each $i\in \mathbb{N}$, $x_i \in [0,1]$.

For  each $i\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a function $\pi_i$ from $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ onto $[0,1]$ such that $\pi_i(\textbf{x})=x_i$.

Now we can define the random variables.

For  each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $X_n$ is a random variable (a function) from $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$X_n(\textbf{x})=n$ if $\pi_n(\textbf{x})\in[0,\frac{1}{n}]$

$X_n(\textbf{x})=0$ if $\pi_n(\textbf{x})\notin[0,\frac{1}{n}]$

It easy to see that each $X_n$ is actually a random variable (it means: it is a measurable function) and that the set $\{X_n\,|\,n\in \mathbf{N}\}$ of random variables are independent.

So we have explicitly presented a sequence $\{X_n\}$ of independent random variables defined by: $P(X_n=n)=\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-\dfrac{1}{n}$.

It is easy to seem that this sequence converge in probability to 0, and NOW, using your argument, we can also see that it does NOT converge almost surely to 0.

**Remark**: The example above is a nice example of sequence of random variables converging in probability but not converging almost surely. The only drawback that I see is that it is far more complex than the usual example in literature (for instance: see *Halmos* $\S$22 exercise 6).

On the other hand, in favor of the example above, we have that it shows that even if we assume the sequence of random variables to be independent, the sequence may converge in probability and do not converge almost surely.

Comment: Haha, I am unfamiliar with too many terms in this solution. I am just a first year undergraduate in Probability and have no knowledge of measure theory. However, I get the gist of what you are trying to say and I understand your example. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your professor is right.  The point is that the statement: "a sequence $\{X_n\}$ of independent random variables defined by: $P(X_n=n)=\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-\dfrac{1}{n}$" is not enough to define a sequence of random variables.

You need to PROVE that there is "a sequence $\{X_n\}$ of independent random variables defined by: $P(X_n=n)=\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-\dfrac{1}{n}$". Or even better: explictly present the sequence.

Consider $\{[0,1],A,P\}$ where the closed interval $[0,1]$ is your sample space, $A$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the set of events, and $P$ is the usual length measure (Lebesgue measure).

The random variables $X_n$ are functions (actually measurable functions) defined in $[0,1]$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$, for instance.

Can you describe the random variables in your example?

**Remark**: It is true that convergence in probability does not imply almost sure convergence, and there are known examples showing it. But, I understand that the question here is about the example you are proposing.

Comment: Hint: unless you are quite a bit more clever than me, the answer to the question in the last sentence is "no".

Comment: Well, the question was posted by Landon Carter, but the whole point is that: to declare "a sequence $\{X_n\}$ of independent random variables defined by: $P(X_n=n)=\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-\dfrac{1}{n}$" is NOT a counterexample, unless you can prove such sequence exists, or, even better, explictly present the sequence.

Comment: Okay, so I get the point. So you are saying that this is not a valid counterexample, right? Because if I take the probability space as defined by you and consider $X_n(\omega)=n$ iff $\omega\in[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ then $X_n,X_{n+1}$ are NOT independent. So can we think of any other probability space? If it doesn't exist, why does it not exist?
So are we left only with the most popular counterexample? Is my counterexample of no value?

Comment: Yes, Landon.  And please note if you take $X_n(\omega)=n$ iff $\omega\in [0,\frac{1}{n}]$ then $X_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ are not independent  AND $X_n$ converges almost surely to 0.  So, this sequence of $X_n$ is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your  example should be $P(X_n=1)=1/n $ and $P(X_n=0)=1-1/n$.
To show that $X_n$ does not converge almost surely. Here you can do 
Let $A_n(\epsilon)=\{ |X_n|\geq\epsilon\}$
and 
let $B_m(\epsilon)=\cup_{n\geq m} A_{n}(\epsilon)$

Hint:

1. Show that $X_n\to 0$ a.s iff $P(B_m(\epsilon))\to 0$ as $m\to \infty$
2. From your example, show that $P(B_m(\epsilon))=1 $ for all $m$.

You can calculate $P(B_m(\epsilon))$ as follow

$P(B_m(\epsilon))=1-P(X_n=0 \ \text{for all} \ m\leq n)$

$P(B_m(\epsilon))=1-(1-\frac{1}{m})(1-\frac{1}{m+1})\ldots$

$P(B_m(\epsilon))=1-\lim_{k\to\infty}(\frac{m-1}{m}\frac{m}{m+1}\ldots \frac{K}
{K+1})$

$P(B_m(\epsilon))=1-\lim_{k\to\infty}(\frac{m-1}{K+1})=1$

Comment: Why did you change your answer? I did see this suggestion before but what's so special with $0/1$ sequences?

Comment: it just makes things simpler to work with !

Comment: You proved that a sequence $\{X_n\}$ of independent random variables defined by: $P(X_n=1)=\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-\dfrac{1}{n}$ does not converge almost surely. BUT, it does NOT prove such sequence exists (or explicitly presents such sequence).